# Conditional C# breakpoint?

Tags: c#, debugging, if-statement, foreach, breakpoints

I'm debugging a `foreach` loop which will iterate well over 1000 times - so I only want a breakpoint within the loop to break for a particular item.

So...

```
foreach(Employee employee in employees)
{
//DO SOMETHING
//BREAK HERE WHEN employee.Id == '2342'
//DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

Do I have to write an `If` statement and some dummy code within it and break it that way? That the only way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just adding to the previous answers. 
Use Conditional Breakpoints.

[image]

You can specify the condition like below 
[image]

Comment: With > 1000 iterations, leppie's answer is better. While you have to edit the code to do this, it is much faster. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11290503/282143

Answer (score 22):

```
if (employee.Id == '2342') Debugger.Break();
```

Alternatively, you can set a conditional breakpoint in VS, but from my experience, that is incredibly slow.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using anything other than the express editions of VS right click on the breakpoint and click Set Condition.

Personally I'd use this approach as I'd consider it bad practice to modify your code to debug it.

Otherwise you're forced to do it your way.

Answer (score 3):

Use a VS debugger with conditional breakpoint, via UI.

The **easiest** and **fastest** way imo.

[The Ultimate Visual Studio Tips and Tricks Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/03/set-a-simple-breakpoint-condition-vstipdebug0021.aspx)

Comment: it's *extremely* subjective. I, personally, use them every day and find much faster then "dirting" my code with something temporary. If I can avoid writing DEBUG code inside my production code, I do that.

Comment: @leppie I did not know that, worth considering if you're running over a few million records - thanks!

Comment: @Tigran: Try it on some performance sensitive code, or on a heavily called method. Go make some coffee and hope the breakpoint has been hit.

Comment: *may be* it will *execute* faster, but, again I, personally, would do that **only** if there is not way to do that, or disturbs me in some way from UI. Cause don't like adding debug stuff to my code. When I say *faster*, I mean not debugger execution, but breakpoint setup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional breakpoints in Visual Studio.

Right click on the breakpoint and choose conditional and then put in your clause.