# Stop on breakpoint when condition is true

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I have a foreach and want to stop on breakpoint only when some value is true.

Right now I use the following way - add some extra code only for debugging:

[image]

but I don't want to write some extra code, is it possible to implement it without developing?

Comment: Visual Studio has [conditional breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290485/conditional-c-sharp-breakpoint